# Statsmodels package is not letting me inherit a function. I get unexpected keyword argument even though the function needs an input parameter

Tags: python, class, statistics, data-science, statsmodels

so the way the **FTestAnovaPower** function works is, it takes 5 parameter but one need to be left as None and the function calculates whichever argument is left as None. My problems is, i want to generate a list of values for one parameter (the one thats None) while keeping the other values constant, hence the for loop.

`

```
class smpl_pwr(statsmodels.stats.power.FTestAnovaPower):
    
    def __init__(self, effect_size=None, nobs=None, alpha=None, power=None, k_groups=None, vals = None):
        #super().__init__(effect_size, nobs, alpha, power, k_groups)
       
        X_func = statsmodels.stats.power.FTestAnovaPower()
        
        self.effect_size = effect_size
        self.nobs = nobs
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.power = power
        self.k_groups = k_groups
        self.vals = vals
       
    def new_lst(self):
        
        smpl_size = []
        for x in vals:
            smpl_size.append(X_func.solve_power(self, effect_size, nobs, alpha, k_groups, power=x))
    
        return smpl_size
```

`

I want to be able to generate a list or an array of values but all i get memory address.

Comment: What's the actual problem/error? The title suggests there's a keyword error, but at the end of the question you mention memory addresses in the return? What code do you run with this class to produce the problem? // The `new_lst` method refers to several variables without a `self` prefix, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: sorry i change it a bit after i posted the question and took out the parent class (i couldnt get that to work either). honestly, i just want it to work doesnt matter how. `x = smpl_pwr(effect_size=0.4, nobs=15, alpha=None, power=0.8, k_groups=2)` this gives me memory address......i read that this may work with a "decorator" but im not even sure what that is. im new to python coming from MatLab.

Comment: `k_groups` isn't one of the solvable parameters it seems, so there are really only 4.  You want to provide one of those (always power?) as a list, and two others as fixed, and get the list of solved values for the fourth?